# Variable does not update in while loop

Tags: python, while-loop

Why doesn't current_score update in the while loop? First time posting, couldn't find the answer online. I guess it's a scoping issue halp

```
def main():
    player_1 = input("Player one: ")
    player_1_score = 0
    player_2 = input("Player two: ")
    player_2_score = 0
    num_sets = int(input("Points for a win: "))
    current_score = "%s (%i : %i) %s" % (player_1, player_1_score, player_2_score, player_2)

    while player_1_score < num_sets > player_2_score:
        round = int(input("Who won this round? (type 1 for player one; type 2 for player two"))
        if round == 1:
            player_1_score += 1
        else:
            player_2_score += 1

    print(current_score)
pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Where do you instruct it to update. Note that string formatting like `...%...` is evaluated **once**...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
current_score = "%s (%i : %i) %s"

while something:
    # do the update
    print(current_score % (player_1, player_1_score, player_2_score, player_2))
```

Here `current_score` is just a string containing the format specifiers. All the magic happens when you apply that `format_string % (data)` syntax to it. Then you get a new string that'll hold the formatted output.

Comment: That's pretty smart. So does that mean that using '%' just stores current values in a string variable? And when i reuse that variable it just gives me the string not the "%s (%i : %i) %s" % (player_1, player_1_score, player_2_score, player_2)

Comment: @qutija, pretty much: the `%s` and `%i`  themselves are merely format specifiers (i.e. just characters).

Answer (score 0):

You have to reinitialize current score with the new values after the new values are set in the loop before printing out:

```
def main():
player_1 = input("Player one: ")
player_1_score = 0
player_2 = input("Player two: ")
player_2_score = 0
num_sets = int(input("Points for a win: "))
current_score = "%s (%i : %i) %s" % (player_1, player_1_score, player_2_score, player_2)

while player_1_score < num_sets > player_2_score:
    round = int(input("Who won this round? (type 1 for player one; type 2 for player two"))
    if round == 1:
        player_1_score += 1
    else:
        player_2_score += 1

    current_score = "%s (%i : %i) %s" % (player_1, player_1_score, player_2_score, player_2)
    print(current_score)
pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```